Paypal integration into flask bad request error
Hi first i want to apologize for my bad english because i'm french and also it's the first time i use stackoverflow to ask a question so i may not have a perfect question form.
So i have to create a webapp to sell product and for this i need to add an automatic paypal payment system so first my script create an order and this work but the problem is that after i pay, when paypal redirect me to the return url, i want to get the token in the url to after make a request to get the order details when paypal redirect me i get a code 400 with bad request error and if i try to go on another page of my web app in the same tab where paypal redirect me, i still have the same error but if i go on another tab the error disapear.
This is the code that create an order (it work) :
@app.route('/product/<int:product_id>/order', methods=['POST'])
def order(product_id):
    product_details = database_handler.get_product_details(product_id)
    user = product_details["user"]
    user_detail = database_handler.get_user_info(user)
    print(user_detail)
    if 'username' in session:
        username = session['username'] + '-'
        random_numbers = ''.join(random.choices(string.digits, k=4))
        username += random_numbers
    else :
        username = 'guest-'
        random_numbers = ''.join(random.choices(string.digits, k=4))
        username += random_numbers
        
    auth = get_paypal_auth_headers()
    
    headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'PayPal-Request-Id': username,
        'Authorization': f'Bearer {auth}',
    }
    
    print(headers)
    
    random_numbers2 = ''.join(random.choices(string.digits, k=4))

    data = {
        "intent": "CAPTURE",
        "purchase_units": [
            {
                "reference_id": username+"-"+ random_numbers2,
                "amount": {
                    "currency_code": "EUR",
                    "value": product_details["price"]
                },
                "payee": {
                    "email_address": user_detail[4]
                }
            }
        ],
        "payment_source": {
            "paypal": {
                "experience_context": {
                    "payment_method_preference": "IMMEDIATE_PAYMENT_REQUIRED",
                    "brand_name": "EXAMPLE INC",
                    "locale": "fr-FR",
                    "landing_page": "LOGIN",
                    "user_action": "PAY_NOW",
                    "return_url": "https://localhost:5000/product/order/confirm",
                    "cancel_url": "https://example.com/cancelUrl"
                }
            }
        }
    }

    json_data = json.dumps(data)
    response = requests.post('https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders', headers=headers, data=json_data)
    repjson = response.json()
    
    second_link = None
    for link in repjson.get('links', []):
        if link.get('rel') == 'payer-action':
            second_link = link.get('href')
            break

    print(second_link)

    return jsonify({'redirect_url': second_link})

and this is the code that have to check for the order details, btw if i enter manually a link that's look like the link i get from paypal, the code work but when it's when i'm redirect from paypal i have those error with 400 bad request
@app.route('/product/order/confirm')
def confirm_order():
    auth = get_paypal_auth_headers()
    
    order_id = request.args.get('token')
    
    headers = {
        'Authorization': f'Bearer {auth}' ,
    }
    
    response = requests.get(f'https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/{order_id}', headers=headers)
    print(response)

